# The type 'Calendar' was not found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, calendar

I tried to create a date picker in a xaml page as follows:

```
<Calendar />
```

However, VS is giving me a type not found error. Is there a reference I need to include for this to work?

Comment: hope you have the namespace xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation included in your xaml

Comment: What calendar are you trying to use? As far as I know, there's no built-in calendar control in Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *DatePicker*  control available in SilverLight toolkit for Windows Phone 7.
You can refer to [windows phone geek article](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization) tutorial to get started.

Answer (score 0):

The `Calendar` class is only the datatype to use with date and time calculations. To select a date from UI you should use `DatePicker` control as mentioned by `op_amp`

See MSDN for usage: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx)